# Calling Linq To SQL queries residing in classes from code behind.

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql

I am using `ASP.NET Web Forms/C#`.I am having a page `Customer.aspx`.I have created `CustomerBLL` class in which I plan to use `Linq To SQL` queries to perform all `database` related tasks.

Consider this example.Here is a method called `GetDateFormat()` in my `CustomerBLL` class which returns Date format from `database`.Here is the code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data;

namespace CwizBankApp
{
    public class CustomerBLL
    {
        public string GetDateFormat()
        {
            using (var db = new DataClasses1DataContext())
            {
                var format = db.CODEs.Where(code => code.NAME.Equals("dateformat")).SingleOrDefault();  
                return format.DRNAME;   
            }
        }

    }
}
```

From `code behind` I am calling this function inside of another function like this.

```
public void RetrieveDateFormat()
        {
            //In this function we retrieve the date format
            //from the database to identify if it is british or american


           var format = CustomerBLL.GetDateFormat();  

            //The global variable gDateFormat stores the format
           if (format != null)
           {
               Global.DateFormat = format;
           }
```

I am calling the function and storing the result first and then checking if it is null or not.Should I be doing this way or Should I check if it is null or not in the `CustomerBLL.cs` file itself?

What is better way to do this.Is my way of calling the function `GetDateFormat()` feasible.

Also is this approach of maintaining `Linq` queries in such class files and then calling them from `code behind`  considered to be a good practice?

Can somebody tell me if I am heading in the right direction or not?

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: you should look at repository pattern

Comment: @COLDTOLD Can repository pattern be used with Web Forms.Can you point out few articles on the subject.If possible.Thanks.

Comment: Vote up for a detailed and well-explained Question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your way of calling the function is ok. However, you should check for null within CustomerBLL.cs.

Comment: So you recommend that I should check for null in .cs file and just use the result in the code behind.

Comment: yeah, don't call it cs file. Just call it business logic class.

Comment: so do you think my approach is recommmended , if at all there are logic to perform then should I do it in code behind?

Comment: your approach is absolutely good. Like i said earlier, perform your logic in your BLL classes only. Code Behinds (Your interface) should only invoke these classes.

Comment: i hope i have answered your question and any confusion is cleared.

Comment: Thanks ya to a extent.So I just need to call the functions in the BLL right.Perform my logic there itself and just present data in the presentation layer.

Comment: Marking the answer as I am not going with repository pattern.Please change the answer with more details as this answer is just more like a comment.If possible include an example as in future it will help someone else with the same problem.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

here are couple of good examples of how to use repository pastern with web-forms

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx

http://forums.asp.net/t/1808905.aspx/1?Repository+Architecture+Using+WebForm+in+C+With+N+Tier+Architechure

http://code.google.com/p/nhibernate-repository-example/

http://www.expertbloggingon.net/post/2011/11/23/CSharp-Repository-Pattern-Design-Patterns-in-Action.aspx

Comment: I will go through the links and in case of further assistance get back to you.Thanks.