# Not all code paths return a value

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql

I am having this `Linq To SQL` query which is taking Customer Category from `database`.The CustCategory will be defined already.Here is the query.

```
public IList<string> GetAccountType()
        {
            using (var db = new DataClasses1DataContext())
            {
                var  acctype = db.mem_types.Select(account=>account.CustCategory).Distinct().ToList();
                if (acctype != null)
                {
                    return acctype;
                }
            }

        }
```

Currently I am getting an error that `Not all code paths return a value.`If I am always certain that the value is there in the database then do I need to check for `null`,If I need to check for `null` then how do I handle this.
Can anyone help me with this.
Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Since your function returns a `List` of account types, I'd call it `GetAccountTypes` (note the plural `s`).

Comment: @Heinzi Thanks a lot for that.I am doing all database operations in seperate classes and then I try to call these methods from code behind ,will yourecommend this approach.Is it good.

Comment: @Heinzi Can you help me with this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11305761/calling-linq-to-sql-queries-residing-in-classes-from-code-behind

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since `Enumerable.ToList` never returns `null` (see the *Return Value* section of [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx)), you can safely remove the `if`.

EDIT: Note that, no matter what your database contains, `acctype` will *never* be null:

- If no value is found in the database, the return value will be an **empty list** (which is different than `null`).
- If one record is found and its value is null, the return value will be **a valid list** with one entry, whose value is null. Still, the list itself is *not* `null`.

Comment: So you recommend that I dont need to check that , but if I am doing some other query and if it is null then what do I return.Thanks.

Comment: @freebird: I've extended my answer to address your question.

Answer (score 3):

What happens if:

```
if (acctype != null)
```

Is null? What is your method supposed to `return`?

You need to return something

Comment: That is what is confusing me , what should I return in that case.

Answer (score 3):

This is not about LINQ to SQL, the method `GetAccountType()` must return `IList<string>`. You should return `return acctype;` and then check this returned list later using [`Any()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.any.aspx), something like:

```
if(GetAccountType.Any()){
     //not empty
}
```

Answer (score 3):

How about something like this for a fairly clean and readable solution?:

(**Note, updated:** removed the check for null, since it would clearly not have any effect).

```
public IList<string> GetAccountType()
{
        var acctype = new List<string>();
        using (var db = new DataClasses1DataContext())
        {
            acctype = db.mem_types.Select(
                         account=>account.CustCategory).Distinct().ToList();
        }

        return acctype;
    }
```

Comment: Worth a try , not a bad idea.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to return a value from your function:

```
    public IList<string> GetAccountType()
            {
                using (var db = new DataClasses1DataContext())
                {
                    var  acctype = db.mem_types.Select(account=>account.CustCategory).Distinct().ToList();
                    if (acctype != null)
                    {
                        return acctype;
                    }
                }
                return acctype;
            }
```